# Laravel - [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL - MAC OS

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I've looked at multiple posts about this issue on stackoverflow but i'm still having the same problem:

The following are listed in the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

ENV File:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=owe
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

i restart apache, rebooted computer and i'm getting the following error when i do a migrate:

```
me$ php artisan migrate
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0


[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

Comment: This is not related to Laravel in any way. Are you running Windows or Linux? Your paths look like Linux, but your file extensions (.dll) sound Windows

Comment: mac os 10.9. The contents were taken from php.ini located in /etc

Comment: It is the pdo driver issue. Check your path well .

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

brew install php55-pdo-pgsql

Thanks,

Comment: brew services start postgresql